# extraneous input 'X' expecting {'X'} on the Antlr4-c3

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am trying to implement a custom language with Antlr4-c3 Lexer and Parser.

But, the error "extraneous input 'EXECUTE' expecting {, 'PROCEDURE', EXECUTE} on the Antlr4-c3" occurs.

Here is my Lexer and Parser code.

MyLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar MyLexer;

PROCEDURE:  'PROCEDURE';
EXECUTE:    'EXECUTE';
FILE:       'file';

COLON:          ':';
LPAREN:         '(';
RPAREN:         ')';
LBRACKET:       '[';
RBRACKET:       ']';
LBRACE:         '{';
RBRACE:         '}';

Upper_ID:       [A-Z_] [A-Z0-9_]*;
ID:             [a-z] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
WS:             [ \n\r\t] -> channel(HIDDEN);
NL:             [\n\r];
```

MyParser.g4

```
parser grammar MyParser;

options { tokenVocab = MyLexer; }

translationunit
:
    statement* EOF
;

statement
: 
    procedureDefinition
    |   execute  
;

execute
:
    executeFile
;

executeFile
:
    EXECUTE FILE
;

procedureDefinition
:
    PROCEDURE procedureName LBRACE statement* RBRACE
;

procedureName
:
    Upper_ID
;

paramName
:
    ID
;
```

Testcode

```
PROCEDURE ASDF {}
EXECUTE file
```

It works using the test code "PROCEDURE ASDF {}" without the "EXECUTE" keyword.

I guess that the keyword "EXECUTE" is recognized as an ID. I changed the order of tokens in Lexer (to recognize the token 'Execute' first).

Comment: Your grammar works fine: https://pasteboard.co/DuL5s5G5ykbU.png You might not have regenerated your parser classes recently: you need to regenerate them after every change of your grammar.

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I have divided from whole of the .g4 file to the lexer and parser. But, I didn't edit the script to generate the lexer file. I misunderstood for generating the lexer file automatically via importing in parser file.

Comment: No problem. In case you have no further question, feel free to remove your question.